# Select the cell that your if statement triggers at and select that cell in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Fairly new to VBA.

I'm trying search a column for a specific value, and then select that cell in order to cut and move it.

All i have right now is:

```
Dim cel As Range

Sub Opdaterstatus()

For Each cel In Range("H1:H100")
    If cel.value = "Fakturering" Then

        MsgBox (cel.value)

    End If

Next cel


End Sub
```

This finds the cells i want, but **my problem is targeting the actual cell** the if statement triggers on. There is hopefully and most likely an easy way to achieve this.
The `MsgBox` is purely for testing purposes.

Comment: `cel.cut` look at the properties and methods of the `range` object `cel` is that type

Comment: Once the loop discovers a cell with a value of "Fakturering" it's your `cel` variable. Now you can do different stuff with it. You can get the range cel.address for example or you can copy and past or cut that range.

Comment: Thank you guys - That gives me something to play around with! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
Call Range("H1:H100").Find(What:="Fakturering").Cut(Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

where "A1" is the address of destination cell.

Logic: in `Range("H1:H100")` perform `Find(What:="Fakturering")`, then `.Cut` found cell and paste it to `Destination:=Range("A1")`.

Of course you may loop until .Find become Nothing. Do not forget to alter Destination...

---

> Is it possible to cut a preset number of cells to the left of the cell?

No problems.

```
strAddress = Range("H1:H100").Find(What:="Fakturering").Address
Range(Range(strAddress), Range(strAddress).Offset(2, 1)).Cut Destination:=Range("A1")
```

Logic: we search the value and get the address of found cell. Then we get a rectangle range, where left-upper corner is found cell `Range(strAddress)` and right-lower corner is 2 row down and 1 column to right `Range(strAddress).Offset(2, 1)`. We cut it and paste into destination.

Comment: Wow - Thank you! Very neatly explained.
Is it possible to cut a preset number of cells to the left of the cell? 
Ex: If "Fakturering" is found in cell A4, but I also want cells A1:A3 to be cut and moved as well?

Comment: you may wish to check the existence of `Range("H1:H100").Find(What:="Fakturering")` before proceeding with the cut, to avoid any errors if Fakturering is not found and the presence of more than 1 if possible.

Comment: See my solution below - Feel free to correct it (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following to select the cell, and the rest of the data to the left of that cell:

```
Dim cel As Range

Sub Opdaterstatus()

For Each cel In Range("H1:H100")
    If cel.value = "Fakturering" Then

       Range(cel, cel.Rows.End(xlToLeft)).Cut

        cel.Offset(5, 0).Insert


    End If

Next cel


End Sub
```

Comment: It is too difficult to verify your code. `End(xlSome)` is very capricious and self willed when empty cells present in `Worksheet.UsedRange`. I'm afraid always when I see it.

Comment: `cel.cut cel.Offset(5, 0)` I think will do it, the method `cut` has a `destination` argument